# Merge PHP multidimensional-array on key, parent keys and depth. In other words an array to a binary search tree.

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have an array that I am trying to merge. The merging is dependent upon the key, the parent keys and the depth of the array. I can manipulate the array in a number of ways to achieve unique key values. The outcome is technically a binary search tree. I have attached two files json_in.txt is what I currently have and json_out.txt is what I want. You will notice that the json_in file has some unique key names in order to merge and the json_out file just has "name" and "children" keys. My plan was to use preg_replace_all to remove the digits from the json string after the array was merged, but if you know a better way then great!

Again, I am trying to make the json array in json_in.txt into json_out.txt and I can manipulate the key of json_in to whatever is needed in order to accomplish this.

[json_in.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_uKNNJmSsBUNHpOX2FMVTcxcjA)

[json_out.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_uKNNJmSsBURWZnYVVHUmVZSlE)

Comment: And what is the question? In which part do you have a problem?

Comment: I have a JSON array in json_in.txt and I am trying to merge it into what is in json_out.txt. My problem is I do not know how to merge the json_in array.

Comment: Take a look at [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).
And [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).